# What do the two values in the FPS meter imply respectively?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

A question that has been bothering me for a long time -

You can toggle on "show framerate" in the display settings in Java.

[image]

`237/129`
I believe 237 to be the current framerate of the game. But what does 129 mean?

Comment: Average or lowest recorded, I guess?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/9m04b9/what_is_the_other_number_on_show_fps_option/), those numbers should be average / minimum framerate.